# .htaccess rewrite with optional custom POST variables

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've looked around on here to try and find a solution to my problem with no avail. Or I may have missed it.

Okay so I have a .htaccess rewrite rule setup:

```
# redirect all calls to index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Which rewrites all mysite.com/?page=thisroute/thispage or mysite.com/?page=thispage to: mysite.com/thisroute/thispage or mysite.com/thispage

Is there a way to pass custom POST variables as well? How could I pass a form through this format without calling the php file that processes it directly?

Ex: mysite.com/thispage/?name=scott&this=that etc.

Comment: Your original rewrite will pass `POST` variables without any problems. You should try it.

Comment: How the F*** did i miss that? Wow. Im not sure what i did to reproduce an error with it but its working fine now! Thanks!

Comment: I see what i did. I added an extra "/" to the end of it causing it to look for a non existent page.

Comment: POST data is sent in the request body, not the url/query string. Unless your rewrites force a client-side redirect, POST data will not be affected.